# How to connect a Java application through a BlueCoat proxy?

Tags: java, proxy

I´m trying to connect a Java application through a BlueCoat proxy, an I´m getting an HTTP status of 407, with a message that says that "credentials are missing"...

Does anyone have some Java code to read an HTML page through this kind of proxy, using integrated security?

Answer (score 1):

I think the built in Java http connection classes do not support proxies. Try the Apache HttpClient at: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x instead.